# how to extract a number from the line in unix

Tags: awk, grep, tr

I need to find the first occurrence of the attribute `ICount` and its value must be returned. Only the number from the attribute. How to get it?

```
< FCount = "1" ICount = "0" Ccount= "1">
```

Comment: "thou shalt not use regex to parse xml"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grep` and `sed` to a) get the integer (!) number following `ICount` (with any number of digits) and b) removing the `ICount` specifier:

```
grep -o 'ICount = "[0-9]\{1,\}' | sed 's/.*"//'
```

Answer (score 0):

Via `awk`:

```
awk -F"ICount *= *\"" '{sub(/".*/,"",$2); print $2}'
```

*Example*

```
% <<<'< FCount = "1" ICount="0" Ccount= "1">' | awk -F"ICount *= *\"" '{sub(/".*/,"",$2); print $2}'
0
```

or also all other attributes

```
% <<<'< FCount = "1" ICount="0" Ccount= "1">' | awk -F"Ccount *= *\"" '{sub(/".*/,"",$2); print $2}'  
1

% <<<'< FCount = "1" ICount="0" Ccount= "1">' | awk -F"FCount *= *\"" '{sub(/".*/,"",$2); print $2}' 
1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use alone tool:

```
sed -n '/.*ICount\s*=\s*"\?/{s///;s/[^0-9].*//;p;q;}' file
```

more classic

```
sed -n 's/.*ICount\s*=\s*"\?\([0-9]\+\)"\s.*/\1/p;/ICount\s*=/q' file
```

or by grep with PCRE

```
grep -m1 -Po 'ICount\s*=\s*"?\K[0-9]+' file
```